# how can I add a PdfPTable as footer in last page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to add a PdfPTable as page footer **only to the last page** of the generated PDF document. The table will have 4 columns of the same width. I have tried other solutions I found here and in other sites to no avail. I have set the bottom margin to different values to leave space to the footer and I have tried several tips to add a PDF footer, but still nothing is shown.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
   // The document creation

   Document prDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 15f, 15f, 10f, 50f);
   PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(prDoc, Response.OutputStream);

   // The event manager
   prPageEvent pdfEvent = new prPageEvent();
   pdfWriter.PageEvent = pdfEvent;
   prDoc.Open();
   .
   .
   .
   public class prPageEvent : PdfPageEventHelper {
      public PdfTemplate template;
      public PdfContentByte cb;
      BaseFont bf = null;

      public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
         try {
            bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            template = cb.CreateTemplate(PageSize.A4.Width, 50);
         }
         catch (DocumentException de) {
         }
         catch (System.IO.IOException ioe) {
         }
      }

      public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
         base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

         PdfPTable f = new PdfPTable(4);
         f.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin;

         f.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("first")));
         f.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("second")));
         f.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("third")));
         f.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("fourth")));
         f.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin+5, document.PageSize.Height-35, writer.DirectContent);

         // Only the following simple text has worked so far, but I cannot set 
         // the exact width to each column with this approach.

         //template.BeginText();
         // template.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false), 8);
         // template.SetTextMatrix(0, 40);
         // template.ShowText("first   second   third   fourth");
         //template.EndText();
      }

      public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
         base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
         BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
         System.String text = "OnEndPage";
         float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);
         iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;
         cb.BeginText();
         cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
         cb.SetTextMatrix(pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(30));
         cb.EndText();
         cb.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetLeft(40) + len, pageSize.GetBottom(30));
      }
   }
```

Comment: I have followed examples like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796525/add-a-pdfptable-to-bottom-of-page-in-itext

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032614/itextsharp-creating-a-footer-page-of

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this was not to create a class inheriting from **PdfPageEventHelper** and override its methods, but to write the content directly in the PDF document just before the document gets closed by creating a **PdfPTable** object and write it directly with the **WriteSelectedRows** method.
There was no need to use the **OnCloseDocument** method for something that needs to appear in the document only once at the end of it.

My final code:

```
Immediately after printing the header and the content...

// Table for final footer.
float[] cols = new float[] { 137, 10, 137, 10, 137, 10, 127 };
PdfPTable f = new PdfPTable(7);
f.SetWidthPercentage(cols, PageSize.A4);

// Populate the table
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell("Lorem", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 1) );
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell(" ", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 0));
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell("Ipsum", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 1));
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell(" ", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 0));
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell("exquisitaque", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 1));
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell(" ", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 0));
f.AddCell(pdfUtils.newCell("responsum", detail_font_size, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, 1));

// Write the footer using absolute positioning.
f.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, prDoc.LeftMargin, 75, pdfWriter.DirectContent);

// Close the document
pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
prDoc.Close();
```